# Parameter type for multitypes in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, flowtype

I wanna create type for function parameter. Pseudocode below. Explaining, what I want to reach: args could be array of objects `{[name: string]: any}[]` or it could be array of objects and boolean value `{[name: string]: any}[] & boolean` and or operator between them `|`, return object `{[name: string]: any}`, so far this code doesn't work, how I can fix it or reach same result?

```js
const someFunc = (...args: {[name: string]: any}[] | ({[name: string]: any}[] & boolean)): {[name: string]: any} => {
  // ...
  return output;
}
```

Comment: An object cant be a boolean?!?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not quite

```
type SimpleObject = { [name: string]: any }

function a(...params: (SimpleObject | boolean)[]): SimpleObject {
  params.forEach(param => {
    // param is either a boolean or SimpleObject
  })

  return ...
}
```

`{ [name: string]: any }[] & boolean` doesn't really mean... anything

you don't have to declare `SimpleObject` separately, you can do it inline, I just find it cleaner

Answer (score 0):

As you have to do typechecking afterwards, just do:

```
 function someFunc(...args: any[]) {
  //...
 }
```

Comment: @tyler nearly every object fullfills `{ [name: string]: any }`, therefore you NEED to do additional type branches, so the type at the beginning doesnt really matter

Comment: sure, but `...args: any[]` will accept `someFunc("something")` which is invalid according to the boolean/object spec in the OP.